# Difference between setting a property directly and using its setter?

Tags: objective-c

What is the difference between these two?

- `self.view.color = [UIColor redColor];`
- `[self.view setColor:[UIColor redColor]];`

Comment: There is no functional difference between these two lines of code. In both the cases you are calling setter method to set the color. As color is the property of self.view therefore you can call it by any way.

Comment: Goutham, please take the time to actually spell out all the words in your title and question. One of the aims of Stackoverflow is to be a repository of knowledge, and knowledge is useless if it can't be found by searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing.

- With `self.view.color = ...` the property's setter in called implicitly.
- With `[self.view setColor:...]` you call the setter explicitly.

More in detail: `UIView` has a `color` property something like:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor* color;
```

In Objective-C this automatically defines an underlying ivar `_color`, and generates code for the setter and getter.  (What code is generated depends on the modifiers `nonatomic`, ... you specify.)

When you type `self.view.color = ...` the compiler sees that your `color` is a property, and internally replaces it with `[self.view setColor:...]`.

Comment: [There a two subtle differences](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37180333/104790) between dot notation and sending an explicit message.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Thanks for adding that.

Answer (score 0):

None, however that would be `setColor:`, not `setcolor:`

```
[self.view setColor:[uicolor redColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Mainly it is a syntax issue, both call the same setter so you can use both equally depending which one you personally prefer :)