# Whats the difference between setting a property in an object through dot notation vs setter?

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, setter

Looks like there is some subtle difference between setting a property through dot notation vs setter.

In my objective-C code, I have a property that can be set to either an instance of class A or class B.  So I declare it as **@property  id delegate**

Both class A and class B have same properties and methods.  Just the implementation (functionality) is different if you call methodM1 on one vs the other.

I see that following lines don't work (using property directly through dot notation)

```
 self.delegate = [[Class A alloc] init];
 self.delegate.property1 = @"ABCD" ; //Does not work, get an error that property1 not defined on id
```

But following line works

```
[self.delegate setPropert1:@"ABCD"] ; //works
```

What is the difference?  Is it that in the setter case, it knows that there is at one class that responds to setProperty1 method so compiler allows it?  if yes, it looks like the answer to Q below (which was also my original understanding) is incorrect.  I.e dot notation does not get replaced by setter.

[Difference between setting a property directly and using its setter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901858/difference-between-setting-a-property-directly-and-using-its-setter)

Comment: With regard to your last paragraph and the linked question - the answer in that other question is perfectly correct as long as the sender isn't of type `id`.

Comment: I answered a similar question [where I shed a bit more light on the difference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37179987/104790).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `self.delegate` is typed as `id`. You can send any message to an `id`, so it is legal to say

```
[self.delegate setProperty1:@"ABCD"];
```

The compiler just lets go of all control and lets you crash the program if this message doesn't work out, because this is an `id`.

But for properties there is no such loosening of control. To use a property, you must have an actual type for which that property is defined. Thus you could say

```
((ClassA*)self.delegate).property1 = // ...
```

Or

```
((ClassB*)self.delegate).property1 = // ...
```

But you can't say

```
self.delegate.property1 = // no, because self.delegate is an `id`
```

However, this is just a matter of notation. Even if you could say `self.delegate.property1` this would be just another way of saying `[self.delegate setProperty1:]`, so nothing is lost just because you can't use that notation.

Comment: Your answer sufficiently answers the question of why Xcode is happy allowing dot notation in one case and not the other, but it's probably worth mentioning that the actual *difference* in the case where Xcode is happy with the dot notation is nothing.

Comment: @nhgrif There *is* one important difference. The compiler needs the static type to find the property declaration. In the declaration the accessor names might be defined to non-default names. This is often the case in Apple's frameworks for boolean properties: `@property (getter=isHidden) BOOL hidden;`. In this case there is an actual difference between code emitted for `receiver.hidden` and `[receiver hidden]`. I think that's the reason the compiler insists on static typing for dot notation.